# Impacts of having unused JAR files in CLASSPATH

Tags: java, performance, jar, classpath

I've read so many Q&A here about tools available to find out *unused* JARs, such as:

1. [loosejar](http://code.google.com/p/loosejar/)
2. [Classpath Helper](http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/)

My question here is, are there any impacts (such as loading of classes into memory, performance,  etc.) of having unused JARs in the classpath either at compile time or run time?  Question applies to both running as a Standalone program and Web Server (Apache Tomcat), though I initially thought about only Standalone programs.

**NOTE:** I'm running JDK 6u32 (64-bit).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are there any impacts (such as loading of classes into memory, performance, etc.) of having unused JARs in the classpath either at compile time or run time?

There is going to be a small impact.  When the class loader (or the compiler's equivalent) starts, it has to read the index of each JAR file to find out what classes are in each JAR.  If you've got unnecessary JARs on the classpath, the classloader has more work to do, and will (at least temporarily) use more memory to cache the indexes.

This applies to all kinds of Java application.  Other related impacts are:

- the extra disk space needed to hold the unused JARs, and
- for unused JARs that are part of a downloadable installer or container, the extra time and network bandwidth needed to do the download.

**The question that you didn't ask** ... is whether these impacts are significant.  The answer is "Generally No" ... but the more useless stuff you have on the classpath, etc, the greater the impact is going to be.

---

IMO, a more important problem with having unused JARs on the classpath is that it is likely to increase your maintenance overheads.  For example, if there are old unused JAR files that happen to have vulnerabilities, someone is liable to spend time checking and upgrading those JARs in response to a security scan ... not realizing that it doesn't affect *actual* security, and is (arguably<sup>1</sup>) a waste of time.

<sup>1 - It is certainly a waste of time in the sense that you wouldn't have needed to expended if the unused JAR had been removed in the first place!</sup>

Comment: So that *small impact* is applicable at both compile time and run time?

Comment: Yes ... in both cases.  And not usually worth worrying about in either case.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is not performance as the cost is relatively small and only on loading new classes.  The main problem is maintainability.  For example, when a library needs to be upgraded, you can waste alot of time testing the application still works ok with the new version only to find the library was not used. (Say you have a new library which needs a newer version of a library you are already "using")

Comment: I couldn't clearly understand this point -- `when a library needs to be upgraded, you can waste alot of time testing the application still works ok with the new version only to find the library was not used`.  Can you clarify on this?

Comment: Say you have log4j version 1.1, but you want to use library X which needs log4j 1.2 for some reason.  You can't just drop in version 1.2 until you determine it doesn't break your application. So you retest your application using 1.2 to see if it still works and waste alot of time because you are not even using log4j. If you only have libraries you are actually using, this would not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has an impact - because the JVM looks for necessary classes in the JARs of the CLASSPATH. It also makes sense to keep sealed JARs, to tell the JVM not to look for related classes in other JARs.

P.S.: javac is also a java program, for the record.

Comment: However, the caching of JAR file indexes means that the overhead of looking in extra places is minimal.